# VB6 Word find and replace in header Late Bound

Tags: replace, vb6, header

I [found this code](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) for find and replace everywhere with VB6 in Word files, however it is early bound.

However I need it for late bound, since my EXE will be used on different systems, thus I can't use the Reference to Word Library.

What my code needs to do is:
Find Red text in all Word files and replace it with hidden font.

I had it working for the main text, but the header also contains red text and also needs to be hidden.

Here is my current code, which does not replace anything anymore.

```
Private Sub PREP_Click()
Const wdColorRed = 255
Dim oWordApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
Dim fs As Object
Dim rngStory As Object
Dim lngJunk As Long
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim tFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim strDocName As String
Dim strPathName As String
Dim locFolder As String
    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to the file(s) your want to prepare.", "File Preparation", "Type your path here... Make sure it end with a back slash, e.g. C:\myfiles\")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "PREP")
Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "PREP")
Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set rngStory = CreateObject("Word.Range")
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
oWordApp.Visible = False
oWordApp.Documents.Open (oFile.Path)
lngJunk = oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).range.StoryType
'Iterate through all story types in the current document
For Each rngStory In oWordApp.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
'Iterate through all linked stories
Do
  With oWordApp.rngStory.Find
oWordApp.rngStory.WholeStory
oWordApp.rngStory.Find.Font.Hidden = True
oWordApp.rngStory.Find.Replacement.Font.Hidden = False
oWordApp.rngStory.Find.Execute Replace:=2
End With
  'Get next linked story (if any)
  Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
Next
strDocName = oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Name
oWordApp.ChangeFileOpenDirectory (tFolder)
oWordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName
oWordApp.ChangeFileOpenDirectory (oFolder)
Next oFile
oWordApp.Quit
Set rngStory = Nothing
Set oWordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I think the problem is the rngStory part. Please help!

Comment: Please format your code properly. Left-aligned code is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

That code is not early bound Ben. It's late bound.

```
Dim oWordApp As Object
Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Is late bound, every where your dealing with Object your dealing with a late binding.

Answer (score 0):

I used Selection instead of Range and it is working now:

```
Private Sub PREP_Click()
Const wdColorRed = 255
    Dim oWordApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim rngStory As Object
    Dim myDoc As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim strPathName As String
    Dim locFolder As String
        locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to the file(s) your want to prepare.", "File Preparation", "Type your path here... Make sure it end with a back slash, e.g. C:\myfiles\")
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "PREP")
    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "PREP")
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    oWordApp.Visible = False
    oWordApp.Documents.Open (oFile.Path)
    oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Select
    oWordApp.Selection.WholeStory
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=2
    oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Select
    oWordApp.Selection.WholeStory
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
    oWordApp.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=2

    strDocName = oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Name
    oWordApp.ChangeFileOpenDirectory (tFolder)
    oWordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName
    oWordApp.ChangeFileOpenDirectory (oFolder)
    Next oFile
    oWordApp.Quit
    Set oWordApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```